# Blazor CascadingParameter won't update layout when I call it from a function, after an onclick event

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to use CascadingParameter from my Layout to manage the "loading" of my website in a generic way.
But I am not managing to stop the "loading" from the "OnValidSubmit" function of the "inherited page" EditForm, after I have called on "onclick" loading.

Let my show you.
In my MainLayout, I am managing to display a loading h2 or the content of a page whatever it is :

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
@if (load == true)
{
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
} else
{
    @Body
}
</CascadingValue>

@code 
{ 
   public bool load = false;

   //---------------------------
   // Setters
   public void Loading()
   {
      load = true;
   }

   public void StopLoading()
   {
      load = false;
   }
}
```

In an other pages that inherits from that MainLayout, I have an EditForm that will check if username and password matches the database.
If no error, it should call the "Loading" function and then process the search in the database, and then Navigate to the home page.
So I added the "Loading" function to the "onclick" of my EditForm and it correctly displays the loading h2 when I click on the button :

```
    <EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="@TriggerLogin">
       <InputText id="name" placeholder="Email" @bind-Value="user.Username" inputmode="email" />
       <InputText id="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" @bind-Value="user.Password" type="password" inputmode="text" />
       <button class="button-pink" type="submit" @onclick="Layout.Loading">Se connecter</button>
   </EditForm>
```

And then process to make my research in the database with my "OnValidSubmit" function :

```
private async Task TriggerLogin()
{
    if (members.Login(user) == true)
    {
        // Do stuff with accesstoken
        Layout.StopLoading();
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/commandes");
    }
    else
    {
        Layout.StopLoading();
        error = "Wrong password or username";
    }
}
```

BUT my StopLoading() function is not updating my page !
Even if my debugger says that I enterred correctly the function in the Layout, the layout is not entering the "else" of the html part and doesn't display the "@Body".
I tried to use this.StateHasChanged() in the layout (the only place it worked) but I am searching for another solution because then it doesn't show the error message.

How can I do to force only the layout to refresh the html part ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the `error` variable? How do you present it?

Comment: @HenriquePombo It's a local variable in the page that inherits MainLayout. So `private string error`

Comment: Honestly, this is a very messy way of trying to achieve your objective. And I blame the ITab example from Microsoft for it. You don't need to pass anything. Move the loading part to the form component itself and manage the progresses there.

Comment: It is not making much sense to me calling body only after `OnValidSubmit`. Does the place where you are logging in, have another layout? You are displaying an error after displaying body on the layout, it makes sense it won't appear. Have you thought using a [Toast](https://github.com/Blazored/Toast)

Comment: @MayurEkbote Do you mean by managing the loading part in each of my forms in each of my pages ? Because the point is to create a generic solution to manage the loading for all the pages

Comment: It looks like you are manually performing authorization check on each page. You should simply use [Authorize] attribute. For any other type of 'generic' loading, you should put the loading related logic in the components that require time consuming loading.

Answer (score 0):

Normally failing reload can be solved by using `StateHasChanged();` So try

```
public void StopLoading()
{
   load = false;
   InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

--- Edit ---

In case this make looses the local variables it would be an option to move those variables into a Service. In my sample I do it only for load and error but rest can be done like load.

```
public class LoadService {
    public bool Load {get;set;}
    public String ErrorMessage {get;set;}
}
```

Then change you code:

```
@inject LoadService LoadService 
//... html part
@if (LoadService.Load== true)
{
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
}
//... html part
@code 
{ 
   //... html part
   public void StopLoading()
   {
      LoadService.Load = false;
      InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

Set the error Message:

```
private async Task TriggerLogin()
{
   if (members.Login(user) == true)
   {
       // Do stuff with accesstoken
       Layout.StopLoading();
       NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/commandes");
    }
    else
    {
        Layout.StopLoading();
        LoadService.ErrorMessage = "Wrong password or username";
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the Service in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoadService>();
```

Comment: Yes but I am losing my `private string error` that I am filling in the page that inherits MainLayout. When I call StateHasChanged, the Layout pass from the else but it also looses this local variables I modified.

Comment: Do not need to pass my load variable into a Service. I am modifing the load variable that is in my Layout, in the "child" pages with CascadingParameters. But in fact I can use your logic to create a ErrorService that I can inject. So I could invoke StateHasChanged in Layout while having access to the error I stored in ErrorService that I injected in the "child" pages.

Comment: If you are willing to change your answer to specify that I need to store the error in a service, and not the loading value, I would accept your answer ! Best regards